# reactnative controlled-mentions can not replace multi mentions inside string

Tags: react-native, mention

i am using https://github.com/dabakovich/react-native-controlled-mentions to handle mentions inside my chat app, as documents, this is working:

```
import { replaceMentionValues } from 'react-native-controlled-mentions';

const value = 'Hello @[David Tabaka](5)! How are you?';

console.log(replaceMentionValues(value, ({id}) => `@${id}`)); // Hello @5! How are you?
console.log(replaceMentionValues(value, ({name}) => `@${name}`)); // Hello @David Tabaka! How are you?
```

But when i have multi mentions like this:

```
@[demo5](d3f0c3cd-f363-4303-8761-8e190f054be3) @[demo8](8dbafd40-b86f-490a-828d-d11dfe221b43) test
```

the function not working as expected, always convert first mention only

```
replaceMentionValues(text, ({name}) =>  `@${name}`)

=> @demo5 @[demo8](8dbafd40-b86f-490a-828d-d11dfe221b43) test
```

Can someone help my problem

Comment: Your example works for me. Which version are you using?

Comment: did u test my case? Im using react-native-controlled-mentions@3.0.0-alpha.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a bug in the library, but notice that this is a `pre-release`.

Here is my test code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { replaceMentionValues } from 'react-native-controlled-mentions';

const App = () => {

  const test = '@[demo5](d3f0c3cd-f363-4303-8761-8e190f054be3) @[demo8](8dbafd40-b86f-490a-828d-d11dfe221b43) test';

  console.log(replaceMentionValues(test, ({name}) =>  `@${name}`))

  return (
    <></>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I have tested the version `3.0.0-alpha.1` which you can test in [this snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/mentionsapp-300alpha1) and it works as we expect it to work.

However, [here is the same test](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/mentionsapp-300alpha2) using version `3.0.0-alpha.2` and it does not work.

There is already a [reported bug on Github](https://github.com/dabakovich/react-native-controlled-mentions/issues/95).

**Edit:** This seems to be fixed in the newest version of the `3.0` branch. The function `replaceMentionValues` is renamed to `replaceTriggerValues` and the matched strings have changed a little bit, though. There is a valid test case located in [utils.test.ts in the last test case](https://github.com/dabakovich/react-native-controlled-mentions/blob/3.0/tests/utils.test.ts). You can see the new pattern here.

The cause of this issue was located in `constraints.ts` in `3.0.0-alpha.2` which defines the following regex: `const mentionRegEx = /((.)\[([^[]*)]\(([^(^)]*)\))/i;`. In `3.0.0-alpha.1` the used regex is located in `utils.ts` and is as follows: `const mentionRegEx = /((.)\[([^[]*)]\(([^(^)]*)\))/gi;`. The delimiter is not global anymore, thus not all words will be matched.

The new function `replaceTriggerValues` adds the missing `g`.

Thus, either downgrade to `3.0.0-alpha.1` or use the newest version of the `3.0` branch. I have added a comment to the Github issue as well.